# Insert de uma tabela na outra com Auto-increment

Tags: sql, firebird, auto-incremento

Olá, comecei recente com banco de dados e estou tentando resolver um pepino, um zebra mal feita no banco e no sistema, usamos atualmente Firebird.

Veja só:

Tenho tabela PRODUTOS e nela, temos coluna CLASSIFICACAO, esta coluna é uma FK com tabela CLASSIFICACAO, por alguma razão não existe uma validação entre as duas tabelas, para conferir um registro em CLASSIFICACAO(PRODUTOS) com tabela CLASSFICACAO, isso faz um bug no sistema, dai para corrigir tenho que identificar qual registro não esta em uma e na outra e fazer um insert.
Quando é pouco registro, vai na mão, agora quando é muito registro vira um Deus me livre.

Pensei em fazer seguinte comando:

```
delete from CLASSIFICACAO;

insert into CLASSIFICACAO (DESCRICAO) select CLASSIFICACAO from PRODUTOS
```

Minha ideia, seria passar CLASSIFICACAO que esta em produtos para tabela CLASSIFICACAO, copiando informação, problema que em CLASSIFICACAO temos coluna codigo que não esta como auto-increment e não pode ficar **null** logicamente.

Como eu poderia colocar ali para ele ir preenchendo campo codigo, na tabela CAMPO codigo, pertence ao produto, se eu pegar ele, dá bug.

Comment: Qual versão do Firebird você está utilizando? A partir da versão 3 você pode utilizar a função Row_Number para preencher o código, ou nas versões anteriores pode criar/utilizar uma Sequence ou Generator

Answer (score 0):

Então amigo, obrigado pela ideia. Encontrei uma alternativa também, usei *distinct* para agrupar um select e por meio dele fazer o insert na tabela Classificacao, depois ajustei uma generator e uma trigger para tabela.

```
delete from CLASSIFICACAO;
insert into CLASSIFICACAO (DESCRICAO)
select distinct CLASSIFICACAO from PRODUTOS;
```

Mas obrigado, também foi de grande ajuda.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

eu tentaria algo assim,
verificaria apartir de produto quais estão usando um id de classificação que não existe e insert desses id como voce falou:

```
insert into classificacao (id_classificacao)
SELECT p.classificacao FROM produto p
left join classificacao c on p.classificacao = c.id_classificacao 
where c.id_classificacao is null
```

voce pode decompor esta query e rodar so o select para analisar os dados retornados na query, troque o p.classificacao por * e veras os dados do left join

espero que ajude

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).